# Chrome API's onBeforeRedirect not working properly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am developing a Google Chrome extension, and I need to detect redirects so I can perform a certain action (the action is irrelevant, this question simply pertains to the redirect). Thus far I have this code in my background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function (url, tabId) {
    console.log("This is a redirect");
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": url}, function(response){});
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

However, neither the `console.log` or `sendMessage` method is getting called. I tried going to wikipedia.com, google.net, and several other sites that I know redirect the user. Why isn't the extension picking this up?

(And yes, I have put "webRequest" in my permissions under my manifest.json file.)

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you need any other code.

EDIT: Thanks to @ze it's working now, but now it's working a little *too* well. In other words, it's starting to fire now multiple times per page, and when I begin to type the url of a redirect site into the chrome search bar, it also gives me the redirect message. How do I only get it to fire once, when I actually push enter to navigate to the redirect site (and not while i'm still typing)? Here's the new code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function (details) {
    if(details.frameId === 0){
        alert("This is a redirect.");      
        // chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {"message": details.url}, function(response){});
    }
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

Comment: I can't immediately tell you the reason it doesn't execute the `console.log`, but your signature for the handler is wrong - that event returns a single `details` object. Are you sure you're looking in the right console? `tabs.sendMessage` is probably pointless given the timing (the tab is about to unload content scripts or haven't loaded the new ones yet).

Comment: Have you declared host permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: ^ This may be onto the answer. You need host permissions for URLs you capture, not just `"webRequest"`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see your callback for onBeforeRedirect has two arguments while [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRedirect) says that the callback should have one argument: `details`. Then you access url and tabId using `details.url` (or `details.redirectUrl` if you need the new url) and `details.tabId`. 
Also, frames inside a tab may redirect as well so the event might fire more than once. If the code has to run only when the main frame redirects you should add a check like:

```
if (details.frameId == 0){
      //Your code here
}
```

Also, I am not sure why you have `{urls: ["<all_urls>"]}` in the arguments of the `addListener` function. The only argument is the callback.
So, I would write something like:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function (details) {
  if(details.frameId == 0){        
     console.log("This is a redirect");
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {"message": details.url}, function(response){});
  }
});
```

Let me know if this worked out.

Comment: This still isn't working.. I opened the console and turned on the "Preserve Log" option, but when I go to wikipedia.com or google.net, all I get is the standard "Navigated to wikipedia.org/" or "Navigated to google.com" message.

Comment: Maybe you should try different event then. Maybe something like `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted( )`